# Extract pattern from string in R without distinguishing between upper and lower case letters

Tags: r, string, extract

This is a toy example. I want to search within `a` and extract those colors that are listed in `b`. Even if the color does not start with an upper case letter, I want to extract it. However, the output should tell me how the color was used in `a`.

So the answer I would like to get is `#"Red" NA "blue`.

```
a <- "She has Red hair and blue eyes"
b <- c("Red", "Yellow", "Blue")
str_extract(a, b)#"Red" NA    NA
```

I used `str_extract` from 'stringr', but would be happy to use another function/package (e.g., `grep`).

Comment: it is easiest to covert all of your strings to the same case, see the functions ?tolower or ?toupper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this `base R`

```
unlist(sapply(tolower(b), function(x) {
        x1 <- regmatches(a, gregexpr(x, tolower(a)))
      replace(x1, x1 == "character(0)", NA)}), use.names=FALSE)
# "Red"     NA "blue"
```

Or as inspired from @leerssej's answer

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(a, fixed(b, ignore_case=TRUE))
#[1] "Red"  NA     "blue"
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your solution has the same problem as my first attempt... OP wants results to keep the capitalization from `a`

Comment: @DominicComtois  Fixed here too!

Answer (score 5):

stringr has an *[ignore.case()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/stringr/docs/ignore.case)* function

```
str_extract(a, ignore.case(b))#"Red"  NA     "blue"
```

Comment: Thanks. Doing this results in an error message: Please use (fixed|coll|regexp)(x, ignore_case = TRUE) instead of ignore.case(x); So; maybe I should do this: str_extract(fixed(a, ignore_case = TRUE), fixed(b, ignore_case = TRUE))?

Comment: @milan This in not an error. It's just a message, not even a warning. The code provides the correct result. But you can use, e.g., `str_extract(a, (fixed)(b, ignore_case=TRUE))`.

Comment: As I have seen, the suggestion in my last comment was already included in @akrun's edit.

Comment: Thank you, all! This is great but what is the purpose of the message? 'ignore.case()' is implemented and gives the correct output, so why are we advised to use this slightly longer code?

Comment: Per the [*stringr* library's code](https://github.com/hadley/stringr/blob/master/R/modifiers.r), the `ignore.case` function is deprecated. Unfortunately, I can't find the reasons for this decision written down anywhere within my reach. The good news is that the code simply pumps the updated format right in for you (behind the scenes), so I just let it do the extra work for us :-D

Comment: Specifically, the code is as follows(near the bottom of the file): `#' @export` `#' @rdname modifier-deprecated` `ignore.case <- function(string) {` `message("Please use (fixed|coll|regex)(x, ignore_case = TRUE) instead of ignore.case(x)")` `fixed(string, ignore_case = TRUE)` `}` [Indentation unfortunately lost in translation]

Answer (score 5):

With `stringi` one can use the case-insensitive option

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_fixed(a, b, opts_fixed = list(case_insensitive = TRUE))
#[[1]]
#[1] "Red"
#[[2]]
#[1] NA
#[[3]]
#[1] "blue"


# or using simplify = TRUE to get a non-list output
stri_extract_all_fixed(a, b, opts_fixed = list(case_insensitive = TRUE), 
    simplify = TRUE)
#     [,1]  
#[1,] "Red" 
#[2,] NA    
#[3,] "blue"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ignore.case` option provided in @leerssej answer is now deprecated (as noted in comments), but is no longer supported at all.
The [`stringr` syntax supported now](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) is:

```
str_extract(a, regex(b, ignore_case = T)) #"Red" NA    "blue"
```

Answer (score 2):

As a refinement to akrun's answer, you can use the change of case for matching, but still return elements the way they are originally written in `a`:

```
library(stringr)
a <- "She has Red hair and blue eyes"
b <- c("Red", "Yellow", "Blue")

positions <- str_locate(toupper(a), toupper(b))
apply(positions, 1, function(x) substr(a,x[1],x[2]))

## [1] "Red"  NA  "blue"
```

Or, to eliminate the NA...

```
positions <- str_locate(toupper(a), toupper(b))
words <- apply(positions, 1, function(x) substr(a,x[1],x[2]))
words[!is.na(words)]

## [1] "Red"  "blue"
```